# Is there any defined function in Postgres that lets you know what action triggers a trigger?

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, database-trigger

I want to do a trigger in Postgres that it will update a log. My trigger will fire when an update, insert or delete is done.

```
CREATE TRIGGER tr_usuario
    BEFORE INSERT OR DELETE OR UPDATE 
    ON public.usuario
    FOR EACH ROW
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE public.actualizarlog();
```

Since my trigger is fired by any of these three actions, I can't know specifically what action triggered the trigger, but in my log also i want to save tha action that was performed. Is there any defined function in Postgres that let me know what action triggers a trigger?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a special variable `TG_OP` which denotes the operation which caused the trigger to fire. It's a string reading `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, `DELETE`, or `TRUNCATE` respectively. See also: ["42.10.1. Triggers on Data Changes"](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-trigger.html#PLPGSQL-DML-TRIGGER)